# Turn script into variable

Tags: powershell, variables

How can I take the results from the following `foreach` script and turn it into a variable or an output I can later import to something else?

```
$testcsv = Import-Csv C:\useractivity.csv

foreach($line in $testcsv)
{
    $field1 = $testcsv."access path"
    $field2 = $testcsv."SAM Account Name (Acting object)"

    echo $field2, $field1
}
```

Comment: `$variable = foreach ...`

Comment: _I can later import to something else?_ that depends on what the something else is...... Also it should be  `$line."access path"`?

Comment: This script doesn't make much sense as written. Inside the loop you're referring to the collection, not the item. You also need to tell us what you're importing into or what format it needs to be in.

Comment: It would be quite helpful if (a) you showed us the format of UserActivity.CSV, and (b) illustrated what format you want output, and what the "something else" you want to import it to expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = foreach($line in $testcsv)
{
$field1 = $line."access path" #you probably want $line here?
$field2 = $line."SAM Account Name (Acting object)"

echo $field2, $field1
}

# do anything you want with $data here export-clixml, export-csv, etc
```

Alternatively you could just pipe the output of the `foreach` loop to the output stream you need\want.

Comment: I can't figure out how to make an output that I can stream into something.

Comment: @user445408 What do you mean by "stream into something"? What *something*? Another command? Another script?

Comment: I haven't been instructed on what, I am just trying to think if/what's possible to take out of this and input it to something else. I guess I'll wait to see what they want next. My thought was create a variable to place or output some kind of information. Nothing specific right now. ty everyone.

Comment: well, with this answer you already have it in a variable, you can do `$data | export-clixml somepath` to preserve this data on disk in an way that can easily be imported back into powershell and preserve the objects

Comment: @user445408 "*I can't figure out how to make an output that I can stream into something*" - because the `foreach() {}` loop doesn't output to the pipeline, you never can. `$testCsv | foreach { #code here } | something` is the pipeline equivalent.